# How to convert time String to datetime?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I want to convert a String to datetime.

So I'm building this code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '23:00', 103)
```

If I try to execute this code I have this:

> 1900-01-01 23:00:00.000

But if I try to execute this convert:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '24:00', 108)
```

I have this error:

> Converting a varchar data type to datetime generated a value not within the range of allowed values.

Comment: Probably 00:00 is valid time, not 24:00.

Comment: Yeah, try 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime type does not support "24th hour". Its time range is 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997.

Try use instead

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '00:00', 108)
```

For more details check [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) page.